# Calabi flow and Robinson - Trautman equation

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Given a metric $g_{a\overline b}$ defined on a Kaheler manifold $K$, the Calabi flow is defined by the equation:
$$\partial_u g_{a\overline b}=\frac{\partial^2 R}{\partial Z^a \partial Z^\overline b}$$

I know there is a set of conditions on the manifold $K$ at which the previous equation becomes a $Robinson \ Trautman$ equation. What are these conditions? 
Thanks for answers or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what you mean by a *Robinson-Trautman equation*.  I learned that Calabi flow coincides with the Robinson-Trautman equations when the number of dimensions is 2.

A classic reference is [Chrusciel](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-137/issue-2/Semi-global-existence-and-convergence-of-solutions-of-the-Robinson/cmp/1104202620.full), which you should consult for further information.